# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{10}(1-|\sin t|)^n nd t=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{10}(1-|\sin t|)^n nd t=1$?

I use numerical experients, and showed that the above limit is valid. But what is the analytical proof?

It sounds that integrating by parts is not sufficient.

Comment: expand it with binomial sum and integrate each term?

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem can probably deal with it but it's maybe killing a butterfly with a bazooka

Comment: How would it be $1$ anyway? I would have guessed $7$, actually.

Comment: [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+100%281-%7Csin+t%7C%29%5E100+dt+from+0+to+10) is a good numerical integral, and the sequence is monotonically increasing, it cannot decrease to 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By symmetry we can rewrite the integral as

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}7\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}n(1-\sin t)^n\:dt + \int_{10}^{\frac{7\pi}{2}} n(1+\sin t)^n\:dt$$

The term on the right goes to $0$ by squeeze theorem since we have that

$$0\leq \int_{10}^{\frac{7\pi}{2}} n(1+\sin t)^n\:dt \leq n(1+\sin 10)^n\cdot\left(\frac{7\pi}{2}-10\right) \to 0$$

For the remaining piece use the substitution $x = (1-\sin t)^{n+1}$

$$|dx| = (n+1)\cdot(1-\sin t)^n\cdot \cos t\;dt $$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{7n}{n+1}\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\left(1-x^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)^2}} \longrightarrow 7\int_0^1 dx = 7$$

by dominated convergence.

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical example of the [*approximation to the identity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#nascent_delta_function). The relevant result here is:

> **Claim.** Let $a \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $f$ be any bounded measurable function on $[0, a]$ that is continuoust at $x = 0$. Then
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{a} f(x) \cdot n (1 - \sin x)^n \, \mathrm{d}x = f(0). $$

Once we have this result, then using that $3\pi < 10 < \frac{7\pi}{2}$ and the symmetry of $\sin$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{10} n (1-\left|\sin x\right|)^n \, \mathrm{d}x
&= 6 \biggl( \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} n (1-\sin x)^n \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr) + \int_{0}^{\frac{7\pi}{2}-10} n (1-\sin x)^n \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

By the claim, this converges to $6 \cdot 1 + 1 = 7$ as $n\to\infty$.

---

*Proof of Claim.* Substituting $x = s/n$,

$$ \int_{0}^{a} f(x) \cdot n (1 - \sin x)^n \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(s/n) \left(1 - \sin(s/n)\right)^n \mathbf{1}_{[0,na]}(s) \, \mathrm{d}s $$

On the other hand, the concavity of $\sin$ on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ shows that $\sin x \geq cx$ on this interval with $c = \frac{2}{\pi}$. Then, from this and the inequality $1 - t \leq e^{-t}$ together,

$$ (1 - \sin(s/x))^n \leq e^{-n \sin(s/x)} \leq e^{-cs}. $$

This shows that $f(s/n) \left(1 - \sin(s/n)\right)^n \mathbf{1}_{[0,na]}(s)$ is dominated by an integrable function $(\sup |f|) e^{-cs}$, and so, the dominated convergence theorem shows that

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{a} f(x) \cdot n (1 - \sin x)^n \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty}  f(s/n) \left(1 - \sin(s/n)\right)^n \mathbf{1}_{[0,na]}(s) \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} f(0) e^{-s} \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= f(0).
\end{align*}